# Parallel programming in C with no threads or high-level libraries

Tags: c, parallel-processing

I'm playing a bit with parallel programming in C; Hence whatever solution I see in the articles I'm reading are built on top of *Threads* or stuff like *OpenMP*, *MPI*, *Select* on Windows or *Fork* on *nix; I got the following questions:

- Can a single process go-parallel on a single thread and without *Forking* itself?
- Are there any other ways of writing parallel code, but with very basic building blocks that are available in C? Something that could be done by manually moving bits around, purely in C built-in functions -- not using a high-level library that makes use of operating system features?

Also the purpose of the question is to get a better understanding of how parallel programming works in a close-to-metal world. I don't have any interest to do micro-optimizations or reinventing the libraries.

**Update**

I'm basically thinking of writing *Callback* functions and let them get called when an *Event* happened; But I'm not sure if it will make it parallel or not.

Comment: you mean, you want fork equivalent in assembly language?

Comment: @SGG Well, no actually. I'm thinking of something like async javascript to be honest; Making use of _Events_ and _Callbacks_.

Comment: Event triggered calls of "registered" functions do not imply any parallelism.

Comment: @alk Thanks for the input. Any other suggestions on how can I go parallel with bare-bone functions? Nothing fancy, just low-level enough to understand better how parallelism works.

Comment: Why not use C11's threading features?

Comment: @alk Well, as I said I just want to understand how it works; but generally I'm thinking if it's possible to avoid context-switching as well.

Comment: Thread context-switching is not genrated by using threads.  It's generated by those software and hardware interrupts that change thread state.

Comment: Writing Callback functions and let them get called when an Event happened may make it parallel if the events can be called from different threads.

Comment: If you want stuff to run in parallel on the currently popular CPU architectures, then you need more than one core.  That means more than one stack pointer.  That means more than one stack.  That means more than one thread.

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks a lot for the explanation, that makes things much more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a single process go-parallel on a single thread and without Forking itself?

That is up to the compiler. The compiler is free to implement instructions between sequence points any way it wants, although most compilers don't parallellize across multiple cores in single-threaded programs.

Example: Compilers for vector processors (like the Cray supercomputers) or for GPUs (graphics cards) use [unrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding) to parallellize loops.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just curious how does it come that it's up to the _Compiler_ but not the program itself? Does this happen at run-time or compile time?

Comment: C doesn't contain any parallel instruction, so there is no way for a single-threaded program to force the use parallelism.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm getting it correctly: Can I then write the parallel piece of code in _Parallel Instructions_ using inline assembly? That means a process can go-parallel if it makes use of processor's parallel instructions, right?

Comment: Yes, assuming the processor has parallel instructions.

Answer (score 2):

1. *Can a single process go-parallel on a single thread and without Forking itself?* — Nope.
2. *Are there any other ways of writing parallel code, but with very basic building blocks that are available in C?* — Nope.
3. *the purpose of the question is to get a better understanding of how parallel programming works in a close-to-metal world* — close-to-metal parallelism requires assembly language and likely a bare metal (no OS) environment.
4. *I'm basically thinking of writing Callback functions and let them get called when an Event happened; But I'm not sure if it will make it parallel or not* — this by itself does not imply parallelism.